# Can I use a regex or string replace with Apache VirtualDocumentRoot?

Tags: regex, apache, virtualhost

I have an Apache configuration which is something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The idea is that it serves any subdomain request from a directory with the same name.  For instance, the docroot for http://beta-a.example.com becomes `/var/www/beta-a`.

This works fine.

My question is this:  Is there any way to modify the extracted part of the request based on some logic?  Ideally a regex.  For example, I'd like to take all requests like:

- http://beta-a.example.com
- http://beta-b.example.com
- http://beta-c.example.com

And remove everything after and including the `-` so that the docroot would become `/var/www/beta`.  Basically, I'd like to find some way to have alternate host names that get served from the same docroot.  I know of the rule:

> %N.M  insert (part of) the name

But this requires that I specify an explicit length and does not seem to allow any application of logic for the extracted substring.

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly what I am looking for, I'll offer a workaround which I'm using here.  I can add an additional subdomain in the second position which accomplishes almost the same thing.  So using these:

- http://beta.a.example.com
- http://beta.b.example.com
- http://beta.c.example.com

All the above will be served from docroot `/var/www/beta`.